# Python interpret and import problem with env or VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am trying to work on a university project from home. We created a Python environment with virtualenv, all on Windows 7. I work on macOS, but when I clone the repository and launch the environment with

`source/Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/QTLab2122/SingleIRsource/daqenv/Scripts/activate`

the environment is activated. But VS Code does not make me select as Python interpreter the python.exe present in Scripts and gives me error about the import of two packages: serial and niscope, despite being inside Lib. What it brings me back is

"Import" serial "could not be resolved"
"Import" niscope "could not be resolved"

Is it due to the environment being created on Windows 7 and not macOS? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Does VSCode really not let you select the interpreter? I have a program that is created on a Windows, and my VSCode on my Mac lets me select the interpreter. Everything works fine tough.

Comment: why don't you use `venv` a standard Python module. Is the Virt-env a subdir of your workspace? Maybe you need to restart VSC and then select the interpreter? Does it work if you set the python exe path yourself in the `settings.json`

Comment: I tried to restart VSC, but nothing. Neither restart nor set the setting.json with `{"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "./daqenv/Scripts/python.exe"}` have changed the situation. The env is the daqenv directory. I'm working at the same level, not inside. But with the PC lab, we work in the same situation!

Answer (score 1):

Could you find these packages in your virtual environment on your mac? I think you need to reinstall these packages.

You can take `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to get the packages list on windows, and reinstall them on your mac through `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: Yes, in the end, it is the solution that I have adopted. I thought there was a "less laborious", faster method, instead, I find myself forced to create a local environment for myself by copying the packages.

Comment: I still have doubts about it. I'm doing some tests to make the requirements.txt file. The point is that when I go to my repository, when I run the command ```pip freeze > requirements.txt```, it creates the ```requirements.txt``` file for me, however when I go to read its contents, there are some packages and libraries that I have installed on my computer, for example: qiskit, which my project must not submit, because we do not use it.

Comment: I also tried to add the -l flag ```pip freeze -l > requirements.txt```, but in the file, I keep seeing many libraries that I don't use, which are not present in the environment. For example, one that I use is niscope, present in the Lib folder, but which is not present in the requirements.txt file!

Comment: @Frostman Please execute `pip --version` to check which pip you are using.

Comment: It should be the latest, pip 21.3.1

Comment: @Frostman Which location, which environment.